# xslt seeking text from a parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I hope to be able to answer other peoples questions soon, but in the meantime I hope someone may be able to answer mine.

here is a sample from an xml file I have...

```
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2">
    <td colname="1">Common stocks 87.33%[This Tag]</td>    (b)
    <td colname="2"/>
    <td colname="3"/>
    <td colname="4"/>
    <td colname="5"/>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="3">
    <td colname="1">&lt;2&gt;Health care&amp;lt;softreturn&amp;gt;21.27%</td>
    <td colname="2"/>
    <td colname="3"/>
    <td colname="4"/>
    <td colname="5"/>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="4">
    <td colname="1"/>
    <td colname="2">Gillan Sciences [Asset Type]</td>  (a)
    <td colname="3">26,522,142</td>
    <td colname="4">1,132,761</td>
    <td colname="5">4.12</td>
  </tr>
```

.... and what I would like to do is to take the 'td' tag, represented here as (a) and replace the text 'Asset Type' with the text from the first parent 'tr' node that has an attribute of type="categoryhead" and with a child 'td' node containg the text 'This Tag' represented here by (b). In other words where the original XML has 'Gillan Sciences [Asset Type]' I would like it to display 'Gillan Sciences Common stocks'.

This is what I have so far, an xslt file that only does anything if the parent node is the immediate parent or if I specify the 'level' attribute. Ideally I would like the query to just be able to swim upwards until it finds the first 'tr' parent node with type of 'categoryhead' and a child 'td' node with 'This Tag' in the text.....

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="v4:td[contains(text(),'Asset Type')]/text()">


        <xsl:variable name="ReplacementTag" select="'Asset Type'"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lev" select="../@level"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-this">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$ReplacementTag" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="../../preceding-sibling::v4:tr[@type = 'categoryhead'][1]/v4:td[contains(text(), 'This Tag')]/text()" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

The 'v4' is the abbreviation of the namespace I am using by the way.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.
Many thanks,
alex.

Comment: How should the algorithm know that it shouldn't include the ` 87.33%` part of that value?

Comment: That much I don't know yet I'm afraid. I'm very much new to this.

Comment: The point I'm making is that you have to clearly define your requirements and expected behavior. We can't make up your requirements for you.

Comment: My apologies. I guess I thought I would worry about that after getting this first part to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next XSLT will do most of the job, but won't remove the `87.33%` from the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pref="http://example.org/uri" xmlns="http://example.org/uri" exclude-result-prefixes="pref">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pref:tr[@type = 'detail']/pref:td[contains(., '[Asset Type]')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '[Asset Type]')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before((preceding::pref:tr[@type = 'categoryhead']/pref:td[contains(., '[This Tag]')])[last()], '[This Tag]')" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark. That does indeed appear to fix it. I do have another question though. If I modify the xml so that "[This Tag]" is in both preceding nodes; in this case "Common Stocks" AND "Health Care" what should I change so that I get "Health Care" as if I try with this xslt it is picking up "Common Stocks" instead. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What would the requirement/rule be if there are two `[This Tag]` texts found?

Comment: Judging from the wording of the question, it seems like he wants to use the one that's closest to the starting point of the search, so I reckon this would work: `substring-before((preceding::pref:tr[@type = 'categoryhead']/pref:td[contains(., '[This Tag]')])[last()], '[This Tag]')`.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help. That was indeed what I was trying to acheive and it looks like I have it working now. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.